# Finding a path in a matrix in recursion

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to solve a problem in a course that I am taking, finding the longest path in a matrix that contains numbers - with a specific difference between the numbers.

I have private methods that check in which direction I can do, but now I am trying to find the "depth" of the slope.

I am keeping a maxDepth variable for each dive - and assigning it to "depth" if it's the deepest - for some reason, depth remains at 0 all the time.

```
private static int longestSlope(int[][] mat, int num, int i, int j, int depth, int maxDepth ){
        if (canUp(mat, num, i, j)) {
            maxDepth = longestSlope(mat, num, i - 1, j, depth, maxDepth + 1);
            if (depth < maxDepth) {
                depth = maxDepth;
            }
            maxDepth = 0;
        }
        if (canDown(mat, num, i, j)) {
            maxDepth = longestSlope(mat, num, i + 1, j, depth, maxDepth + 1);
            if (depth < maxDepth) depth = maxDepth;
            maxDepth = 0;
        }
        if (canRight(mat, num, i, j)) {
            maxDepth = longestSlope(mat, num, i, j + 1, depth, maxDepth + 1);
            if (depth < maxDepth) depth = maxDepth;
            maxDepth = 0;
        }
        if (canLeft(mat, num, i, j)) {
            maxDepth = longestSlope(mat, num, i, j - 1, depth, maxDepth + 1);
            if (depth < maxDepth) depth = maxDepth;
        }

        return depth;
    }


private static boolean canUp(int[][] mat, int num, int i, int j) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (mat[i - 1][j] == -1) {
        return false;
    } else if (mat[i][j] - mat[i - 1][j] != num) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[image: Screenshot from IntelliJ]

Comment: Does it return `0` in the end, or does it loop infinitely and give a StackoverFlowError due to recursion? Since you do a recursive call when you can go up, does it inside do a recursive call again because now it can go down? Or do you have something inside the `can`-methods to prevent that? Could you perhaps add the implementation of the `canUp` and `canDown` methods to your post?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Added, thank you.
I am trying to store maxDepth inside depth - but instead it stays 0

Comment: I assume you start by calling your method with `dept` and `maxDepth` = 0. Lets say your first move is down so you make a recursive call and `maxDepth` is now 1 and then you move right and `maxDepth` = 2. For the next recursive call you can not move any more and return `depth`, which has never been updated, so it is 0. This sets `maxDepth` to 0 in the outer call and when you then update `depth`  there it will also be 0 and so on. Looks to me like you need to update `depth` _before_ making a recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `depth` after checking whether you can move in each direction. This will cause a problem for you when you reach a point where you cannot move in any direction. Since `depth` is updated after the recursive call, your method would return `0` and that value would be assigned to `maxDepth` in its parent recursive call. You want to have a base case check for when you reach a point where you cannot move in any of the 4 directions. Something like this should do the trick:

```
private static int longestSlope(int[][] mat, int num, int i, int j, int depth, int maxDepth ){
    if(canUp(mat, num, i, j) == false && canDown(mat, num, i, j) == false && canRight(mat, num, i, j) == false) && canDown(mat, num, i, j) == false) {
        // this means that you cannot move in any of the 4 directions: the base case
        return maxDepth;
    }
    if (canUp(mat, num, i, j)) {
        maxDepth = longestSlope(mat, num, i - 1, j, depth, maxDepth + 1);
        if (depth < maxDepth) {
            depth = maxDepth;
        }
        maxDepth = 0;
    }
    if (canDown(mat, num, i, j)) {
        maxDepth = longestSlope(mat, num, i + 1, j, depth, maxDepth + 1);
        if (depth < maxDepth) depth = maxDepth;
        maxDepth = 0;
    }
    if (canRight(mat, num, i, j)) {
        maxDepth = longestSlope(mat, num, i, j + 1, depth, maxDepth + 1);
        if (depth < maxDepth) depth = maxDepth;
        maxDepth = 0;
    }
    if (canLeft(mat, num, i, j)) {
        maxDepth = longestSlope(mat, num, i, j - 1, depth, maxDepth + 1);
        if (depth < maxDepth) depth = maxDepth;
    } 
    return depth;
}
```

For future reference, it's always a good idea to determine what your base case is in a recursive function, and to return whatever value it is you are calculating. Doing so will help you avoid such subtle bugs!